# Find all complex numbers z that satisfy the equation:

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all complex numbers z satisfying the equation:

$z-|z|=8+4i$

I only know one way i.e. assuming $z=x+iy$, $z=x+iy$ but I don't know how to proceed with this approach. Can someone help, please.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  write is as:
$$
z=|z|+8+4i
$$
Take the conjugate on both sides:
$$
\bar z = |z|+8-4i
$$
Multiply the two:

$$
|z|^2 = \big(\,|z|+8+4i\,\big)\,\big(\,|z|+8-4i\,\big) = \big(\,|z|+8\,\big)^2+16
$$

Solve the latter for $|z|\,$, ***and if it satisfies*** $|z| \ge 0$ then replace in the original equation to get $z$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  Edited the last line to spell out the ***existence condition*** (which, in this case, is not satisfied, so the equation has in fact no solutions).

Comment: Using this method, I'm getting $|z|=-3$, which is clearly not possible.

Comment: Expanding we get $16|z| + 80 = 0$ and hence there is no such $z$.

Comment: @Aweygan You are right, there are no solutions (that would be $-5\,$, rather). I edited the post to make that point more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such $z$. This can be seen geometrically as follows: The given condition says that the diagonal of the rhombus with vertices 0, $z$ and $-|z|$ is along $8+4i$. The mid point of the diagonal is $4+2i$ in the first quadrant, one vertex ($-|z|$) is on the negative $X$ axis and hence geometrically, there is no place for $z$.

Comment: That's a nice geometric argument (+1). It could also be stated algebraically as $\operatorname{Re}(z) - |z| \le 0 \lt 8\,$.